# why string prints junk value,if we give it size?

Tags: c++, string

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string a("Hello World",20);
    cout<<a<<endl;
  
    return 0;
}
```

I get output as "Hello WorldP". Why?
Usually we initialise string only with a data.But here i gave size.But it takes junkees.
So do i prefer not giving size?

Comment: Because you are telling your string, that the passed (C-)String is 20 characters long, even though it is not. As such, it takes 'whatever comes after the terminating 0' in memory and appends it to the string. The `<<` finally takes 'the entire string' and not just 'the string until the first `\0`.

Comment: Why did you put that `,20` into `string a("Hello World",20);`? What are you trying to achieve by that?

Comment: buffer overflow demo: https://godbolt.org/z/6Y4fYMq1q using address sanitizer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally this is called [garbage in, garbage out](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_in,_garbage_out).

From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string):

> Constructs the string with the first count characters of character string pointed to by s. s can contain null characters. The length of the string is count. The behavior is undefined if [s, s + count) is not a valid range.

The behavior of your program is undefined because `"Hello World"` is a `const char[12]` and trying to access characters up to index `20` via the `const char*` (resulting from the array decaying to pointer to its first element) is out of bounds.

---

The actual use case for that constructor is to create a `std::string` from a substring of some C-string, for example:

```
std::string s("Hello World",5);  // s == "Hello"
```

Or to create a `std::string` from a C-string that contains `\0` in the middle, for example:

```
std::string s("\0 Hello",5); // s.size() == 5 (not 0)
```